# how to include zend phtml file to other phtml file

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm use **zend framework 1**.

and I need to include phtml file inside another file and send parameter to first file.

Ex:

I have **indexController.php**

and I have `$numberOfItem` defined inside the controller

I need to **render (include)**  **menu.phtml**  inside **index.phtml** and send `$numberOfItem` varible to it

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use **zend partial** to do that

in your **index.phtml** do

```
echo $this->partial('yourfolder/menu.phtml', array('numberOfItem' => $numberOfItem));
```

and in your **menu.phtml** you can read the print the variables using

```
$this->numberOfItem
```

Comment: How to get the variables defined inside menu.phtml into index.phtml in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Its [Zend partial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial).

In the IndexController, you will pass the numberOfItem value to the corresponding view as usual.

```
    $this->view->numberOfItem = $numberOfItem;
```

Then, in the index.phtml :

```
    echo $this->partial('viewfolder/menu.phtml', array('numberOfItem' => $this->numberOfItem));
```

in the menu.phtml:

```
     echo $this->numberOfItem;
```

The **viewfolder** in the partial's path will be the same as the relative folder from the "view/scripts". For example, even if both your index.phtml and menu.phtml are in the same folder "application/views/scripts/index", you need to pass the path to partial as **index/menu.phtml**